# Upgraded RPi and lost my functionality using gpio zero

Tags: gpio, python

Recently upgraded my RPi and lost my LED functionality
I've installed all kinds of things to attempt to resolve this and no success
Thanks

```
pi@JASPER:~/controls $ python controlscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controlscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import time,os,datetime,subprocess,signal,sys,gpiozero,argparse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .output_devices import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 26, in <module>
    from colorzero import Color
ImportError: No module named colorzero
```

Comment: What do you mean by "upgraded" what did you ACTUALLY do? Python 2 is obsolete. What OS?

Comment: `colorzero library` is not Raspberry Pi specific ... that makes your question about Linux, not about RPi

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the distro package was not included in bullseye:

```
> apt search python | grep -i colorzero

python-colorzero/oldstable,oldstable 1.1 all
python-colorzero-doc/oldstable,oldstable 1.1 all
python3-colorzero/oldstable,oldstable 1.1 all
```

However, it's still available, so you could just try installing it: `apt install python3-colorzero` (assuming you are using python 3).

If it is already installed, it may be because it is in a more specific module directory than just "python3".

```
> echo /usr/lib/python*
/usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.9
```

Yours may or may not be the same.  These are fine since the current default python is python 3.9; check yours with `python --version`.  If it is, eg., python 3.11, it won't access stuff installed into the python 3.9 directory.

You may then want to use `pip3` to install, which should match the interpreter version.

If you want to use python 3 but for some reason the system is stuck on 2 as a default, on RpiOS or other Debian derived installs you can change that with (first make sure there is a python 3 with `python3 --version`):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.x 1
```

Where `3.x` is the value you get from `python3 --version`.

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.18

Comment: That is a bit weird because it implies you are still using a pre-bullseye system (where python 3 became the default).  I'll add a note at the end above about this.

Comment: pi@JASPER:~ $ python3 --version
Python 3.9.2

Comment: It was recommended from elsewhere to try using python3 to execute the script, and here were the results.

Comment: import time,os,datetime,subprocess,signal,sys,gpiozero,argparse
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
from .input_devices import (
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 37, in <module>
  from .pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pigpio.py", line 166, in <module>
    class PiGPIOPin(PiPin):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pigpio.py", line 174, in PiGPIOPin
    'input':   pigpio.INPUT,
AttributeError: module 'pigpio' has no attribute 'INPUT'

Comment: You should post that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks. Been offline for a while and def not a pro at this forum!